# Link to id element with offset

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed title div on the top whose height is 80px. Now I have a link "how" pointing to a div.

```
<div id="how">
  <!-- Some description here -->
</div>
```

However, when we actually click the link, because the header div is out of flow, it covers the top portion of the #how div. How can I set an offset so that when we click the link, it brings me down the #div link with a offset of 80px?

Comment: could you set up a simplified jsfiddle?

Comment: click a link that brings you to a DIV - isn't there a HTML or JavaScript part missing here? or is there something new in HTML5 that allows for scrolling to elements using anchors?

Comment: You'll probably need to correct the styling on the div to use a margin instead of padding or other related change.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are willing to add another anchor somewhere (which is probably not you first choice), you will need to use JS. [window.scrollTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.scrollTo) would be a good place to start.